# sticky_header: RenderStickyHeader does not meet its constraints

Tags: flutter

Plugin: `sticky_headers` https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> timeHeaders = new List<Widget>();
  Map<int, List<Widget>> roomRow = new Map<int, List<Widget>>();

  double fontSize = 18;
  double leadingWidth = 120;
  double tileWidth = 84; // CHANGE THIS IF NEEDED
  double tileHeight = 30;
  double tileBorderWidth = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    timeHeaders.add(
      new Container(
        height: tileHeight,
        width: leadingWidth,
      ),
    );

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      timeHeaders.add(
        new Container(
          height: tileHeight,
          width: tileWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '$i',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      roomRow[i + 1] = [
        Container(
          height: tileHeight,
          width: leadingWidth,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'HEADER$i',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ];

      roomRow[i + 1].add(Container(
        height: tileHeight,
        width: 75,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lightGreen[300],
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: tileBorderWidth,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'x',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('header'),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: (timeHeaders.length.toDouble() - 1) * tileWidth +
                      leadingWidth,
                  child: StickyHeader(
                    header: Row(children: timeHeaders),
                    content: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          Divider(),
                      itemCount: 21,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return index == 0
                            ? Container(height: tileHeight)
                            : Row(children: roomRow[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
I/flutter (18193): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (18193): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (18193): RenderStickyHeader does not meet its constraints.
I/flutter (18193): Constraints: BoxConstraints(w=540.0, h=594.0)
I/flutter (18193): Size: Size(540.0, 624.0)
I/flutter (18193): If you are not writing your own RenderBox subclass, then this is not your fault. Contact support:
I/flutter (18193): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
```

`624-594=30`, which is the same height as the `tileHeight` variable (set to 30). So something with the vertical listview is off. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. I just added in

`overlapHeaders: true`

inside the `StickyHeader` widget